# Liferay JPA ClassLoader Error

Tags: jpa, integration, liferay

**EDITED (I'm simplifying as my original question was too convoluted):**

Create a portlet plugin in Liferay 6.1.20

Add in your portlet's web.xml a spring context loader

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Add in your application context an instance of an EntityManagerFactory

```
<bean id="localEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

Make sure in your persistance definition you're referencing a JPA Implementation

```
<persistence-unit name="casd" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Watch Tomcat cry

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for interface javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider have different Class objects for the type javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil used in the signature
```

Play with hibernate3.jar, eclipselink.jar, persistence.jar until exhaustion, and realize Liferay is grinning at you.

How would you erase that irritating smile from Liferay's face?
In other words,

**How can I get a JPA provider instantiated in a spring context within a portlet plugin in liferay 6.1.20 without getting a classloader error?**

Comment: wild guess: sounds like you either have some code twice on the classpath or code that assumes a different JRE than you are using. If you look at the classpath, look at what's available to tomcat after deployment, not in your source project.

Comment: Liferay manages the dependencies and classloaders on its own, I have no control over that. I already tried playing moving or removing the jars that could be causing the problem :(

Comment: but if you find out that something ends up twice on the classpath, we can see how to mitigate that. At least the injections at deployment (e.g. when you use the Liferay deploy folder) are transparent and get added to WEB-INF/lib

Comment: It's the classic one: if I remove the provider for the dependencies, I get a ClassNotFoundError. I'm gonna try instantiating the EntityManagerFactory in the portlet instead of doing it in Spring, and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing, same error, althought now it obviously raises at the render phase of the portlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I managed to "solve" the problem moving ecliseplink.jar from /ROOT/WEB-INF/lib to {tomcat}/lib/ext

I don't like it as a solution, having to mess with ext, but it's a take it or leave it situation.